# Keeping Diagonal Consistency for Interpolated Values Across Mesh-Grid 3D Matplotlib Surface Plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to make a 3D Surface plot easier to look at, with a low number of data points. I'm doing this by creating 1000 linearly-connected points in between each of my x and y data points. The flaw with this, is that it expands my data in only orthogonal directions, while leaving disparity along a diagonal axis.

You can see in this plot, the two highest points are diagonal to each other, and have a curved dip between them. However, I wouldn't expect this dip to be there if I had actual data points to represent it. Is there a way to interpolate this more accurately?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import cm
from scipy.interpolate import griddata


x = np.array([1200,  900,  600,  300, 1200,  900,  600,  300, 1200,  900,  600, 300])
y = np.array([32698675.77, 32698675.77, 32698675.77, 32698675.77, 22235099.52, 22235099.52, 22235099.52,  22235099.52, 11117549.76,  11117549.76,  11117549.76,  11117549.76])
z = np.array([ 157039.99991206, 112843.30660347, 86955.86661797, 110282.34660491, 99997.52952157, 211376.31395759, 126638.66680572,  88166.23539093, 246550.43164327, 127657.17661076,  84181.01970028, 111822.90208357])

xyz = {'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z}
df = pd.DataFrame(xyz, index=range(len(xyz['x']))) 
x1 = np.linspace(df['x'].min(), df['x'].max(), len(df['x'].unique()))
y1 = np.linspace(df['y'].min(), df['y'].max(), len(df['y'].unique()))
x2, y2 = np.meshgrid(x1, y1)


xt = np.array([])
for mina in range(len(x1)):
    if mina < len(x1)-1:
            xn = np.linspace(x1[mina], x1[mina+1], 1000)
            xt = np.hstack((xt, xn))

yt = np.array([])
for mina in range(len(y1)):
    if mina < len(y1)-1:
            yn = np.linspace(y1[mina], y1[mina+1], 1000)
            yt = np.hstack((yt, yn))

x3, y3 = np.meshgrid(xt, yt)
z2 = griddata((df['x'], df['y']), df['z'], (x2, y2), method='cubic')
z3 = griddata((df['x'], df['y']), df['z'], (x3, y3), method='cubic')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 1, projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(x2, y2, z2, cmap=cm.YlGnBu)
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
ax.view_init(20, 100)
ax.yaxis.labelpad=20
ax.xaxis.labelpad=10
ax.zaxis.labelpad=20
ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))
ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='z', scilimits=(0,0))
plt.ylim(np.max(y), np.min(y))
ax.set_xticks(np.unique(x))
ax.set_yticks(np.unique(y))
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.tight_layout()

ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 2, projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(x3, y3, z3, cmap=cm.YlGnBu)
ax.set_ylabel('y.')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
ax.view_init(20, 100)
ax.yaxis.labelpad=20
ax.xaxis.labelpad=10
ax.zaxis.labelpad=20
ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))
ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='z', scilimits=(0,0))
plt.ylim(np.max(y), np.min(y))
ax.set_xticks(np.unique(x))
ax.set_yticks(np.unique(y))
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Example of before and after plots are in the code, image below.
[image: Surface Area Plot]

[image: SA Plot2]

Comment: To me the plots look good. Can you describe more accurately where the dip is that you don't want?

Comment: I don't think this is solvable. Imagine applying this to `z(0,0) = z(1,1) = 1, z(0,1) = z(1,0) = 0`, which resembles the relevant corner of your graph. Your method produces `z(0.5,0.5) = 0.5`. To get a different result, your interpolation would have to already know what the data looks like

Comment: The two highest peaks, ones at 900 and 1200 on the x. They reach a high point, but in between them, diagonally, is a dip that goes down to yellow-greenish color. I've posted another angle.

Comment: @Eric I was actually thinking of trying to fit 2d lines along diagonal points, but I would favor having an actual numerical approach rather than a lot of line interpolations. Also, I think this would leave me with the same problem if I wanted to expand the data from points along the lines, the disparities would just be in smaller spaces rather than consistent across larger ones.

Comment: @Eric is right, it's not a priori clear which opposite points should be weighted more. It's like building a tarp (like in [this image](https://media.globetrotter.de/zoom/100591001_a_tarp_10_ul_hilleberg.jpg)). If you apply more strain on the corners of the bars, the middle point will be higher, if you apply more strain on the two bottom lines, the middle will be lower. Equal strains (and that is what the interpolation does) results in the center to be in the middle.

Comment: Why are you drawing the line between the two high points and not the low ones? The algorithm you're looking for would have to break symmetry, such as `interp(-z) != -interp(z)`

Comment: In short: from your data alone, there is no reason to expect a ridge in your plot. Collect more data, or justify a better interpolation using theory. Don't doctor your plot to show what you want it to show, when that's not what the data says

Comment: Well to be fair, the data doesn't say anything about the points in between diagonals. So you could consider the whole plot fake. I'm not trying to doctor this, I wanted the colors to better represent peaks, which they failed to do on the 6-square mesh grid on the left. Also, I understand what you're saying, but from my personal experience with what I'm dealing with, I would very much expect a ridge in that plot. I'm going to try making an algorithm to build the diagonals one square at a time based on adjacent x and y points, instead of building all x's and y's independent of each other.

Comment: You can fix the colors in the original without changing the shape by using linear instead of cubic interpolation

Comment: Linear doesn't seem to change any of the positioning, I don't think there's enough points for that one to make a difference (6 grids can only be arranged so many ways in regards to the same z-axis data)

Comment: Why are you insisting on having ha surface plot with only six data points? I think a simple heat map as you show in the lower panels is more appropriate here.

Comment: In this case, the same problem applies to the birds-eye-view, the orthogonal data is interpolated but the data diagonal to each other is inconsistent with the results. I could make an actual heatmap (this one only has 6 squares for 12 data points, so it's not a literal heatmap), but I'd like to interpolate the points between them; which a heatmap wouldn't show any information for. The point of doing this is more for future use with larger data sets, but I'd like to get it working regardless of the amount of data.